# Positioning windows with applescript on dual monitors

Tags: macos, applescript

I have 2 air applications that I wrote. They auto fullscreen after 10 seconds. Before then, they need to be sent to their proper displays. "app_1" needs to run on display 1, "app_2" needs to run on display 2.

Essentially, I have this code:

```
do shell script "cd /Applications/app_1.app/Contents/MacOS/ ; open app_1;"
```

which works for me flawlessly. Both apps are launched that way, and there is some code for ensuring that the apps weren't already open, and closing them if they were.

I tried to add in a script to position the app after it is launched:

```
do shell script "cd /Applications/app_1.app/Contents/MacOS/ ; open app_1;"
tell first window of application "app_1" to set bounds to {0,0,1920,1080}
```

This gives me an error:

```
app_1 got an error: Can't set bounds of window 1 to {0,0,1920,1080}
```

I tried adding a delay of a couple seconds before the `set bounds`, in case the application hadn't yet launched when the `set bounds` fired off, however this didn't change anything.

I also tried setting the bounds to something like `{100,100,200,200}` just to see if I had the screen coordinates wrong or something, but still the exact same error, only with the `{100,100,200,200}` instead of the original 1920x1080 coordinates.

Anyone have any insight on this? I've been trying to find the solution on google for a couple of hours now.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but... does your app actually respond to "first window", and do its windows actually respond to "set bounds"? In other words, if you run the same "tell" line manually while the app is already up and running, does it work?

Comment: I still get the same error message when doing it manually while the app is already running

Comment: OK, next break it into two parts. What if you just 'tell application "app_1" to first window'? Does that also fail? If so, then your app isn't exposing its windows to scripting. If you think it's supposed to be (e.g, because you've written code to do so, or because AIR claims that happens automatically), that's what you have to fix. If there's no reason to expect that to work, you'll need to use UI scripting (which means assistive access has to be enabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your app isn't exposing the standard "window" class. I don't know if AIR apps are supposed to automatically take care of this and it's not working—if so, you'll want to debug that.

But another alternative is to use UI Scripting to control its windows externally. Instead of this:

```
tell first window of application "app_1" to set bounds to {0,0,1920,1080}
```

Do this:

```
tell application "System Events"
  set position of first window of application process "app_1" to {0, 0}
  set size of first window of application process "app_1" to {1920,1080}
end tell
```

However, this will only work if you've gone to the Universal Access pane of System Preferences and checked "Enable access for assistive devices" (or done the same via API, "sudo touch /var/db/.AccessibilityAPIEnabled", etc.).

Comment: I have done what you suggested and I now get the message "can't set class pcap "app_1" of application "System Events " to {0, 0}